# Right clicks restarts desktop

Tags: windows-10, right-click

When I try to right-click on icons on desktop or folders and files in explorer, it seems like Windows Explorer restarts. No menu is opened, all the currently open programs close and it's like the desktop restarts.

What could be causing this and how can I fix it?

I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: Maybe this can help? https://www.tenforums.com/software-apps/13204-file-explorer-crashes-after-right-click-desktop.html

Comment: Try disabling all add on context menu extension handlers. [ShellExView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) is useful for this.